# Why is CLASSPATH prefixed with JDK path?

Tags: java, javah

While trying to build a library that uses javah, I ran into a classpath issue. Apparently, the classpath is prefixed with the JDK path: please notice *the final search path is wrong*. How should I do instead?

```
elmarco@makai:~/src/sasl/java/CyrusSasl (mingw32 *%)$ CLASSPATH=$PWD javah -o javasasl.h -jni -verbose Sasl 
error: cannot access Sasl
class file for Sasl not found
javadoc: error - Class Sasl not found.
[ Search Path: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/classes//home/elmarco/src/sasl/java/CyrusSasl ]
elmarco@makai:~/src/sasl/java/CyrusSasl (mingw32 *%)$ ls Sasl.java 
Sasl.java
```

Thanks for your help!

(this is jdk1.6.0_24 on Fedora 14)

Comment: You need the JDK classpath use builtin classes like `Object` and `String` Are you trying to replace all the built in classes? (You can do this but I don't know what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Oh I do want the system class, but I want the local "." path to be in the classpath as well. Let me update the question to make it more clear what the problem is.

Comment: You shouldn't have to but it appear you need to add ':' to the start of your class path.  My guess is that the '//' at the start of your path is confusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually avoid the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. This should work (and maybe without a problem):

```
javah -classpath .;<your-path> -o javasasl.h -jni -verbose Sasl
```

If don't need nothing but the local path, then you don't have to specify a `-classpath` option, `.` is the default value.

**Note** - you have to *compile* `Sasl.java` first. `javah` expects a class file. [(Getting started)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html)

Comment: indeed, the Makefile.am build didn't build the .class first. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simply a bug in how the `javah` outputs its actual classpath. What happens is that it has a bunch of places where it searches for built-in classes, and apart from them, it also uses the stuff in `$CLASSPATH`. When it prints the actual classpath used, they do something like this (pseudo code, assuming `implicitEntries` is a list of builtin classpath entries, and `explicitEntries` is a list of the the directories specified in `$CLASSPATH`):

```
print implicitEntries.join(pathSeparator) + explicitEntries.join(pathSeparator)
```

where it should have been

```
print implicitEntries.join(pathSeparator) + pathSeparator + explicitEntries.join(pathSeparator)
```

The following works fine for me:

```
$ ls
Sasl.class  Sasl.java
$ javah -classpath . -o javasasl.h -jni -verbose Sasl     [ Search Path: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/classes/. ]
[Creating file javasasl.h]
[search path for source files: [.]]
[search path for class files: [/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/resources.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/rt.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/jsse.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/jce.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/charsets.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/classes, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, .]]
[loading ./Sasl.class]
[loading /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]
[loading /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Throwable.class)]
[loading /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Class.class)]
[done in 585 ms]
$ ls
javasasl.h  Sasl.class  Sasl.java
```

---

Now, since the header file generation doesn't seem to work for you... are you sure you have `Sasl.class` in the current directory? `javah` works with byte code files, not Java source files.

Answer (score 1):

You show here, that the source file is available ...

```
(mingw32 *%)$ ls Sasl.java 
Sasl.java
```

but missing is the class file (Sasl.class).

```
error: cannot access Sasl
class file for Sasl not found
```

Compile it first.

Comment: you are right! it's been a long time I didn't touch java, and all I need is just a `make dist` to pass. Thanks